# WFFM How to work-around error "Redirect item is null"

Tags: wffm, security

I am building registration pages for my site using WFFM. There are 4 steps in this process which I am handling with a separate form on a separate page. To prevent users being able to access the next step before completing the previous, I am using roles and security and the "Edit Role Membership" Save Action for each form. What I am finding, is that if the "Success Page" item is denied read access for the user (until they submit the form) I get the error message

> *Redirect item is null*

If I was writing some navigation code myself I would I would just wrap my call to `LinkManager.GetItemUrl()` with a security disabler using statement, but I'm not sure if there is a way to achieve that with WFFM?

Another idea is to create intermediate redirect items without any security settings on them and link to those redirect items. When the user arrives on a redirect item, they would get redirected to the secured page and the WFFM form would be able to render the link to the redirect item without any security problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick and dirty approach here is to set the Success Page link as an external link (i.e. just enter `/path/to/your-page` ) this way Sitecore does not check the security when rendering the link.